# How to assign the priority for the multiple stock location on purchase in spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Spree multiple stock locations allows a product purchase.It takes the product from default store and so on . How to assign priority for the locations on purchase.?

Answer (score 2):

You should implement a `Spree::Stock::Prioritizer` and apply the appropriate logic here:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.4.3/core/app/models/spree/stock/prioritizer.rb#L38-L40

Worth to look - [The Prioritizer](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/b3a8969f0ffb3ec3faa507da7785aedbefedfe44/guides/content/developer/core/shipments.md#the-prioritizer)

Comment: I want to add a new method to this model -> https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.4.3/core/app/models/spree/stock/prioritizer.rb#L38-L40, what should be my file name ? Extending Classes -> https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html#extending-classes didn't mention  about nested models.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to class_eval the existing one with `Spree::Stock::Prioritizer.class_eval`. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a good way to subclass and replace Spree's Prioritizer with one that you define.

Comment: Ok.. In which file I should open the class?

Comment: The most sensible place would be `app/models/spree/stock/prioritizer_decorator.rb`

Comment: Yes.. It worked. Any idea, based on what logic store_locations are being selected in spree? Suppose, I have sorted the store locations [A, B, C], and how those will be selected in Spree ?